# Can Cloudera Impala work with Group Separator delimiter ?

Tags: cloudera, impala

We have files with `Group Separator (29)` as the delimiter. I am trying to create a table (using the create table from file option) in the Cloudera metastore to be used by Impala but it does not seem to recognize the delimiter. Options i have used include:

```
"\029", "29", "029"
```

Is this even possible or the Cloudera metastore does not recognize such characters?

Comment: Which version of Impala ? How did you try to create the table ? What was the error ?

Comment: Impala Shell v1.1.1 (83d5868), how i tried to create the table is as i mentioned in the question using the metastore, the error i get is nothing shows up on the preview.. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so with some professional help i was able to solve it and the way to solve is is to use the octal value without the quotes(even though the tool tells you to use quotes).. using \035 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so with some professional help i was able to solve it and the way to solve is is to use the octal value without the quotes(even though the tool tells you to use quotes).. using \035 solved the problem. –